# How can I send data from JS to Bash?

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, shell

I need to process some dynamic data on a webpage using client side JS code only. Then I would like to run a program in my local computer's terminal on the result. The result has simple structure that is trivial to this question. Low cpu usage and latency is required. So I cannot write my result to a mysql database and use shell to keep polling the update.

Comment: This "program in the local computer"'s function cannot be reproduced in the JS?

Comment: It can't. it has to be executed in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to run your JS code on headless browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and then pipe the output to your bash script.

Answer (score 0):

From a regular browser, you cannot run a program on your local computer's terminal.  You would need elevated privileges such as a browser plug-in to do something like that.

This is for security reasons.  Imagine the potential vulnerabilities if an externally loaded web page could run arbitrary programs on your computer.

If the Javascript does not have to be served over the web or viewed in a browser, you can use node.js to run a Javascript script locally on the client and then node.js can exec any external program.  But, this is not in a browser.